# Max Norm of a linear functional

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional with $E=\{f \in C([a,b]); f(a)=f(b)=0\}$ and $$\psi(f)=\int_a^b f(x) dx.$$

Let $\|f\|=\max \, |f(x)| \in [a,b]$ be the norm of $E$. Find the norm of $\psi$ in $E$. I proved that $$\psi(f)=\frac{|\int_a^b f(x) \,dx|}{\max \, f(x)}\leq (b-a)$$ but i'm struggling to prove that $(b-a)\leq \psi(f).$ Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

For every $n\in\Bbb N$ (large enough) take
$$f_n(x):=\begin{cases}n(x-a)&a\le x\le a+1/n\\
1& a+1/n\le x\le b-1/n\\
n(b-x)&b-1/n\le x\le b\end{cases}
$$